# Roots of a polynomial in a normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$.

$L$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

> Express the roots of  $m(x)=(x^2-2)^2-3$ ( the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$)   in  $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ in term of $\alpha$.

Thanks.

Comment: See the answer of Kenta (including the comments to it) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524577/a-normal-extension-of-mathbbq).

Comment: the roots of $m(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ are $\pm \sqrt{2 \pm \sqrt{3}}$ we have $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\right)$ and $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}\right)$ but how does that answer to the question?